# Can't display an imageView from parse in tableview cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, parse-platform

When the iOS app runs nothing shows up in the cells, the image is of type "file" in parse. I don't use the storyboard for this so I cant change the class for the imageView to PFImageView. What's missing?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell
    PFFile *thumbnail = [object objectForKey:@"logo"];
    PFImageView *thumbnailImageView = (PFImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"];
    thumbnailImageView.file = thumbnail;
    [thumbnailImageView loadInBackground];

    cell.textLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"name"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    thumbnailImageView=[[PFImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(9, 9, 30, 30)];
    [thumbnailImageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:thumbnailImageView];

    return cell;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason you can't see the image is because you are loading it in the background and setting it before the data has been obtained from parse. Could you try something like this:

```
// Set placeholder to show before image finishes loading
PFImageView *thumbnailImageView = (PFImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:100];
thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"];

PFFile *thumbnail = [object objectForKey:@"logo"];
[thumbnailImageView setFile:thumbnail];
[thumbnailImageView loadInBackground:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        // Configure your image view in here            
        imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(9, 9, 30, 30)];
        [imageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];     
        [imageView setImage:image];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
    }
}];
```

Try something along these lines.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you mean by och but I just setup an example with an ImageView inside the loadInBackground.. you could probably just do `thumbnail.image = image` and then `[cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];` Not sure if this is what you are asking.

Comment: oops i'm sorry i meant and*. no but I don't have a variable called image or imageView? But I understand your example, But it still doesn't work!!...

Comment: what about using the built in self.placeholder?

Comment: Is the image you are loading definitely there? What do you see if you log `NSLog(@"[object objectForKey:@"logo"]: %@",[object objectForKey:@"logo"]);` ?

Comment: After adding an ImageView with class PFImageView in the cell the using the storyboard, with tag 100, it all worked out fine! Thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

Do you actually need these 3 lines...

```
thumbnailImageView=[[PFImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(9, 9, 30, 30)];
[thumbnailImageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

[cell.contentView addSubview:thumbnailImageView];
```

You are already casting your existing ImageView to a PFImageView...

```
PFImageView *thumbnailImageView = (PFImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:100];
```

Which in turn should be the image view in you table cell. Does `loadInBakground` work well with table cells though? You could hit issues where the row its getting the image for may have already been reused by another image

Comment: Yes to make it look good in the cell. I used to have local images but now I want to use images from parse.com

Comment: so what happens if you comment out those 3 lines of code?

Comment: Is your PFFile set up correctly, i.e. it is actually a PFFile

Comment: yes i think so i tried to check with NSLOG the thumbnail.file url and I could see the correct url for the images. I think that you need to set the imageView class to PFImageView in storybard or something...

Comment: Try creating a custom table cell, that way you should be able to define the image class

Comment: But the problem is that I want to it as a "subview" on the cell, not to the cells imageView. This should be so easy...